# Python- Regular expression syntax. Look for string, delete part and return end

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm struggling with some regular expression syntax.

The answer I am looking for is the word "rubber".  I start with "rububbuber". Basically "ub" has been added before a vowel.  In order to decrypt this to return the word to "rubber", I can't just remove any "ub" combination.  I must look for "ub + vowels"

```
import re

text = "rububbuber"
vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
vowel_string = str(vowels)

def decrypt(text):
    decrypted_text = ""
    pattern = re.compile(r'ub'+vowel_string)
```

I've successfully been able to read "text" to identify the "ub + vowel" pattern.  I cannot figure out how to do the rest, which is in pseudocode below...

I want to iterate over the characters in "text".  Look for the "ub + vowel" pattern. If a character is regular, add that character to "decrypted_text".  If the function finds the "ub + vowel" pattern, pop() the vowel and add it to "decrypted_text" to reconstruct my final word, which is "rubber".

One last note, I don't want this to only work for the word "rubber".  I figured out how to solve only that word.

Comment: Is the transformation bijective?

Answer (score 1):

You may construct a regex like `ub(?=[vowels])` to remove `ub` only when followed with a vowel:

```
import re

text = "rububbuber"
vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
pattern = "ub(?=[{}])".format("".join(vowels))
print(re.sub(pattern, "", text))
# => rubber
```

See the [Python demo](http://rextester.com/KIIH4030) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zioatw/1).

**Details**

- `ub` - a literal substring
- `(?=[aeiou])` - a [**positive lookahead**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that matches a location inside the string that is immediately followed with a character listed in the `[...]` character class, `a`, `e`, `i`, `o` or `u`.

If you need to make it case insensitive add `flags=re.I` to the `re.sub`:

```
re.sub(pattern, "", text, flags=re.I)
```

**If you prefer working with *capturing groups***, use

```
pattern = "ub([{}])".format("".join(vowels))
print(re.sub(pattern, r"\1", text))
```

See another [regex](https://regex101.com/r/Zioatw/2) and [Python demo](http://rextester.com/KLI92915).

Here, the pattern is `ub([aeiou])`. It matches `ub` and then *captures a vowel* into Group 1 (the `(...)` create a so-called [**capturing group**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)). That value can be retrieved during the replacement by using a [**replacement backreference**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) `\1` (but note the backslash is a literal backslash, so either use `"\\1"` or `r"\1"`).

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand this part of your solution: pattern = "ub([{}])" . Even after reading documentation I do not understand the curly braces {}. How do the curly braces capture the "vowels" variable?

Comment: @ErichPurpur That is purely a Python part, it is not related to the regex. It is just a way to pass a variable to the string. Same as you would write `"["+vowels+"]"`. [More details here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#formatspec). To see the actual pattern, just use `print(pattern)`.

Answer (score 1):

More complex lookahead can solve it, but I would simply search & capture ub+vowel, and replace by captured vowel:

```
import re

s = "rububbuber"
print(re.sub("ub([aeiou])",r"\1",s))
```

result:

```
rubber
```

Comment: This is just the same solution I suggested, but based on a capturing mechanism.

Comment: yes, I didn't look at your answer. I just posted mine (after trying to find duplicates). It's simpler to comprehend. What's the problem?

Comment: It is the same and is not simpler.

Comment: yeah I don't see any `\1` in yours, you want me to delete it?

Comment: No, it is up to you, I just note that this is the same idea, and if I were you I'd  just add it as a comment below the existing answer. Also, from my tests (not performed in Python), lookahead solutions like this (where the lookahead is anchored after literal text are usually a little faster than capturing group since there is no replacement operation overhead.

Comment: you know that performance is one of the aspects. simplicity/easiness to understand is another. this question (and answer) isn't exactly rocket science. Someone else than you can come up with a solution. I'm not a lookahead specialist, so I used references.

Comment: To be honest I thought @Jean-FrançoisFabre's solution was easier to understand.  But I appreciate both responses.  No need to fight over it.  Except I don't understand this part:  r"\1"
What is r"\1" doing in this expression?

Comment: @ErichPurpur That `\1` is a replacement backreference to the value captured with the first capturing group. I will have to add this variation to my answer to explain it. I added details to my answer.

Comment: One last question:
in this syntax "ub([aeiou])" can I substitute my "vowels" variable for [aeiou]?

Comment: `"ub([aeiou])"` => `"ub([{}])".format("".join(["a","e","i"]))`

Comment: but you don't have to write the characters as a list. You can use `"aeiou"` in which case no need for `"".join`